# Looping through html elements with the same class and finding the order of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created an image slider that has 3 images and 3 dots, each dot runs a function that loads an image, the first dot the first image etc.

Now what I'm asking is how can I create a loop for the javascript to do the same result instead of repeating myself for each button?

```
<span class="kcslider-dot" id="dot-1"></span> 
<span class="kcslider-dot" id="dot-2"></span> 
<span class="kcslider-dot" id="dot-3"></span> 

$("#dot-1").click(function(){
  currentSlide(1);
})

$("#dot-2").click(function(){
  currentSlide(2);
})

$("#dot-3").click(function(){
  currentSlide(3);
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use [jQuery Data](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
<span class="kcslider-dot" data-slide-id="1" id="dot-1"></span>
<span class="kcslider-dot" data-slide-id="2" id="dot-2"></span>
<span class="kcslider-dot" data-slide-id="3" id="dot-3"></span>

$(".kcslider-dot").click(function(){
  var slideId = $(this).data('slide-id');

  currentSlide(slideId);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[id^='dot-']` selector to select all the elements with `id` value starting with `dot-` then inside the click function get the numeric part after hyphen by doing `split()` on the `id`value:

**USING `jQuery`**

```js
$("[id^='dot-']").click(function(){
  var idNumber = this.id.split('-')[1];
  currentSlide(idNumber);
});
function currentSlide(num){
   console.log(num);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="kcslider-dot" id="dot-1">1</span> 
<span class="kcslider-dot" id="dot-2">2</span> 
<span class="kcslider-dot" id="dot-3">3</span>
```

**USING `JavaScript`**

```js
var elem = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='dot-']");
for(var i=0; i<elem.length; i++){
  elem[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
     var idNumber = this.id.split('-')[1];
     currentSlide(idNumber);
  });
}

function currentSlide(num){
   console.log(num);
}
```

```html
<span class="kcslider-dot" id="dot-1">1</span> 
<span class="kcslider-dot" id="dot-2">2</span> 
<span class="kcslider-dot" id="dot-3">3</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use your class in the selector of jquery and then loop with the function "each". You can use a var that acts as counter o use an attribute in the html for get the parameter of the function "currentSlide"

```
var i = 1
$('span.kcslider-dot').each(function(){
     currentSlide(i);
     i++;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as all of your slides belong to the same class you can use `class`-selector instead of `id`. When you select all slides the output of the selection will be an array and the order will be the same as in the DOM. So after the selection you just may loop through that array and add listener to each element separately specifying certain slide using `index`:

```
let sliders = $(".kcslider-dot");
for(let i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++) {
    sliders[i].click( () => {
        currentSlide(i+1);
    })
}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If the `span` elements are the only children of their parent you could use the jQuery [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) function to load the corresponding image.

Also you can attach the click event to the class instead of the id. That way you only need a single event handler.

e.g.

```js
function currentSlide(index) {
  console.log(index);
}

$(".kcslider-dot").click(function() {
  currentSlide($(this).index() + 1);
});
```

```css
.kcslider-dot {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="kcslider-dot" id="dot-1"></span>
  <span class="kcslider-dot" id="dot-2"></span>
  <span class="kcslider-dot" id="dot-3"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `.each()` of jQuery, it takes `index` as param. Then you just pass the `index` to the `currentSlide()` into the clicked context.

```
$('.kcslider-dot').each(function(index) {
   $(this).click(function() {
        currentSlide(index + 1);
   })
})
```